# How to handle nested tags while reading JSON API data in R?

Tags: json, r, api, web-scraping

I am reading Yelp API data. I tried reading it using Fromjso, but it is not working. I am new in R, so can you help me to read yelpdata in a data.frame? This looks like nested tags to me. I am expecting each tag to look like column name. Following is my code

```
    yelpurl<- api_url
    yelpdata <- readLines(yelpurl)
    json_data <- fromJSON(yelpdata)
    yelpframe<- data.frame(json_data)
    head(yelpframe)
```

Yelpdata looks like

```
    > yelpdata[[1]][[1]]
    [1] "{\"region\": {\"span\": {\"latitude_delta\": 0.0, \"longitude_delta\": 0.0}, \"center\": {\"latitude\": 41.9453333258613, \"longitude\": -87.6459314569375}}, \"total\": 4212, \"businesses\": [{\"is_claimed\": true, \"rating\": 4.5, \"mobile_url\": \"http://m.yelp.com/biz/si-pie-pizzeria-chicago\", \"rating_img_url\": \"http://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png\", \"review_count\": 107, \"name\": \"Si-Pie Pizzeria\", \"snippet_image_url\": \"http://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/photo/EuuO7b8RZaubeJo0ZVzOuw/ms.jpg\", \"rating_img_url_small\": \"http://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/a5221e66bc70/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_4_half.png\", \"url\": \"http://www.yelp.com/biz/si-pie-pizzeria-chicago\", \"menu_date_updated\": 1434364983, \"phone\": \"7733601862\", \"snippet_text\": \"Really good NY style pizza. Awesome service.  \\n\\nThe pizza crust was crispy but chewy (as NY style should be), sauce tangy and toppings on both the sausage...\", \"image_url\": \"http://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/ZNJ-cIaL2ovLXBUt14kBng/ms.jpg\", \"categories\": [[\"Pizza\", \"pizza\"]], \"display_phone\": \"+1-773-360-1862\", \"rating_img_url_large\": \"http://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/9f83790ff7f6/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_4_half.png\", \"menu_provider\": \"single_platform\", \"id\": \"si-pie-pizzeria-chicago\", \"is_closed\": false, \"location\": {\"cross_streets\": \"Stratford Pl \\u0026 Cornelia Ave\", \"city\": \"Chicago\", \"display_address\": [\"3477 N Broadway ST\", \"Lakeview\", \"Chicago, IL 60657\"], \"geo_accuracy\": 9.5, \"neighborhoods\": [\"Lakeview\"], \"postal_code\": \"60657\", \"country_code\": \"US\", \"address\": [\"3477 N Broadway ST\"], \"coordinate\": {\"latitude\": 41.9453333258613, \"longitude\": -87.6459314569375}, \"state_code\": \"IL\"}}]}"
```

Yelpframe looks like

```
> head(yelpframe)
  region.span.latitude_delta region.span.longitude_delta region.center.latitude region.center.longitude total
1                          0                           0               41.94533               -87.64593  4212
  businesses.is_claimed businesses.rating                         businesses.mobile_url
1                  TRUE               4.5 http://m.yelp.com/biz/si-pie-pizzeria-chicago
                                                                    businesses.rating_img_url businesses.review_count
1 http://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/99493c12711e/ico/stars/v1/stars_4_half.png                     107
  businesses.name                                        businesses.snippet_image_url
1 Si-Pie Pizzeria http://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/photo/EuuO7b8RZaubeJo0ZVzOuw/ms.jpg
                                                                    businesses.rating_img_url_small
1 http://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/a5221e66bc70/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_4_half.png
                                   businesses.url businesses.menu_date_updated businesses.phone
1 http://www.yelp.com/biz/si-pie-pizzeria-chicago                   1434364983       7733601862
                                                                                                                                          businesses.snippet_text
1 Really good NY style pizza. Awesome service.  \n\nThe pizza crust was crispy but chewy (as NY style should be), sauce tangy and toppings on both the sausage...
                                                  businesses.image_url businesses.categories businesses.display_phone
1 http://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/ZNJ-cIaL2ovLXBUt14kBng/ms.jpg          Pizza, pizza          +1-773-360-1862
                                                                    businesses.rating_img_url_large businesses.menu_provider
1 http://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/9f83790ff7f6/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_4_half.png          single_platform
            businesses.id businesses.is_closed businesses.location.cross_streets businesses.location.city
1 si-pie-pizzeria-chicago                FALSE       Stratford Pl & Cornelia Ave                  Chicago
              businesses.location.display_address businesses.location.geo_accuracy businesses.location.neighborhoods
1 3477 N Broadway ST, Lakeview, Chicago, IL 60657                              9.5                          Lakeview
  businesses.location.postal_code businesses.location.country_code businesses.location.address
1                           60657                               US          3477 N Broadway ST
  businesses.location.coordinate.latitude businesses.location.coordinate.longitude businesses.location.state_code
1                                41.94533                                -87.64593                             IL
```

Yelpframe is not in proper column rows format.

Comment: You've already loaded `rjson`, so why not use `fromJSON(yelpdata)`. It would help if you were more specific about exactly what your desired output is. It doesn't help to include all this code if you've taken out the parts we need to actually run it. In this state the problem is not [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for your input. I tried reading it using fromjson then putting it in data frame    

json_data <- fromJSON(yelpdata)
yelpframe<- data.frame(json_data)
head(yelpframe)   

But output is not in column*row format